# Find the integer values of x which satisfy $\frac{2016}{x+y}+\frac{x}{y+2015}+\frac{y}{4031}+\frac{2015}{x+2016}=2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the integer values of x which satisfy $$\frac{2016}{x+y}+\frac{x}{y+2015}+\frac{y}{4031}+\frac{2015}{x+2016}=2$$

---

I considered $x; y = 0$ and $x; y> 0$ and succeeded, the remaining $x; y <0$ i couldn't solve it. Help me

Comment: As $x=2015, y=2016$ is a solution, choose $a=x-2015, b=y-2016$

Comment: Also : $$4031=29\cdot139$$